# Is it possible to split the pubspec.yaml file into several files

Tags: flutter, yaml

As the title describes, I wonder if it is possible to split the pubspec.yaml file in Flutter into several files. The use case I'm thinking about is generating the imported assets declarations with an import script. But it seems like a bad idea to mix code generation and manual edits in the same file.

So I would like to generate a separate assets import file and import that into the pubspec.yaml file.

Is that possible and if so how?

Change this:

```
flutter:

  assets:
    - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
    - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  fonts:
    - family: SomeFont
      fonts:
        -assets: fonts/SomeFont.tff
```

into something like

```
flutter:
  #import imageAssets.yaml


  #import fontsAssets.yaml
```

Comment: should make a request to add this feature to the YAML parser

Comment: I checked some of the source code and there isn't anything about it. it may be possible to do it using build_runner but that would require running it every time you want to update the pubspec file.

Comment: Maybe you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69663055/share-pubspec-yaml-package-dependency-versions-along-multiple-local-flutter-and)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

`pubspec.yaml` does not support imports.