# Share pubspec.yaml package dependency versions along multiple local flutter and dart packages

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-management, pubspec

My flutter project depends on several local flutter and dart packages to keep things separated and clean.
My folder structure is like this:

```
main-flutter-project
│  lib
|  test
│  pubspec.yaml
│
└── local-packages
│   └── dart-package-1
│   │     pubspec.yaml
│   │
│   └── flutter-package-1
│   │     pubspec.yaml
│   │
│   └── flutter-package-2
│         pubspec.yaml
...
```

Each local package is self contained and can be maintained without touching the main project.

This structure means that I have many `pubspec.yaml` files where I have to keep the dependencies updated.
When I use e.g. the `bloc` libaray `bloc: ^7.2.1` in say 5 packages, I have to update the version in each `pubspec` file separately when a new version is released.

Is there a possibility to specify those shared package dependency versions in only one place where the other `pubspec.yaml` files refer to?

I've seen this e.g. with Maven where you can specify a property `<junit.version>4.12</junit.version>` and access it from somewhere else `<version>${junit.version}</version>`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We were solving a similar problem.

AFAIK, there's no built-in or recommended way to do this, so we were inventing some hacks.

In our case, we have `core` package that has some shared functionality and common dependencies, if you don't have it, you can still create an artificial one, let's say, `shared_dependencies` package, and specify all the shared dependencies there.

Now, let's say, package `foo` depends on `shared_dependencies` package, and there's dependency `bar` defined in `shared_dependecies` package that `foo` needs to use. There are some ways to do that:

1. Import dependency directly. Since `foo` depends transitively on `bar`, you can just write `import package:bar/bar.dart` and it will work. It's not the best way though:

   - it's bad practice to import transitive dependency (there's even a [linter rule](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules#depend_on_referenced_packages) for that);
   - auto-import won't work;
2. Export package in `shared_dependencies` package. I.e. `shared_dependencies.dart` can contain the following lines:

   ```dart
   export 'package:bar/bar.dart'
   ```

   That means that in your `foo` package you can just write `import 'shared_dependencies/shared_dependencies.dart'` and get access to `bar` content.

   Pros:

   - auto-imports work.

   Contras:

   - if you export several packages, there can be name conflicts (you'll have to hide some names in export);
   - if `foo` package depends on one `bar` package only, it could be weird to import all shared_dependencies.
3. Export in separate libraries of `shared_dependencies` package. You can group some related packages together in different files, e.g.:

   `bar.dart`:

   ```dart
   export 'package:bar/bar.dart'
   ```

   `bloc.dart`:

   ```dart
   export 'package:bloc_concurrency/bloc_concurrency.dart';
   export 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
   ```

   In that case, if you need `bar` package in `foo`, you write `import 'package:shared_dependencies/bar.dart'`; if you need `bloc`, you write `import 'package:shared_dependencies/bloc.dart'`. Auto-imports work as well.
4. Add direct dependency to `foo` package, but don't specify version constraints:

   ```yaml
   bar:
   ```

   This basically means that you need *any* `bar` package, but since `foo` also depends on `shared_dependencies`, its constraints will be taken into account. This may be needed if you're using some executables from `bar` package, as there's a [limitation in Dart SDK](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/23426) that doesn't allow to run executables in transitive dependencies.

In our project, we ended up using `2` for the most commonly used packages, `3` for other packages, and `4` for packages with executables that we need to run.

Comment: Thank you very much for that detailed answer. That definetly helps a lot! Smart approach, providing it via a shared dependencies package. I will reward you the bounty as soon as possible

Comment: one question to `3.`:
Just putting a comment above one or more export statements groups them together by the comment name? Did I understand that correctly? You say you could import all bloc dependencies by importing `shared_dependencies/bloc.dart` but you don't export `bloc.dart` in that example. You only put `bloc.dart` as a comment above the bloc-related exports. That seems odd and I feel like I haven't understood `3.` it correctly

Comment: @tmaihoff I meant it to be in different files, probably the formatting was confusing. I've updated this point, hopefully, it's more clear now.

Comment: ah I see, yeah that makes much more sense. Got it now, thanks!

Comment: @KirillBubochkin How to get method `4:` running with build_runner?
I have a local package for my dev_dependencies and can import it in the `pubspec.yaml` file of the parent like:
`dev_dependencies: my_dev_dependency_package: path: '../path/to/package'`
But this gives me the `Cannot run executables in transitive dependencies.` Error. I'm not really getting how to apply Method `4.` there.

Comment: @vander2675 did you add the dependency to the main packages as well?

Comment: @KirillBubochkin no only to the dev_dependencies

Comment: @vander2675 yeah, with dev_dependencies it won't work, since they apply only to the package that declared them, they are not added to other packages even as transitive dependencies.